# Rolling Sum SQL

Tags: sql, performance, sum

I have a pretty simple SQL requirement but wanting to know what is 'best practice' for the below scenario as I am running into a performance issue.

I have a list of teams, each week/round these teams pay a game fee. If a team doesn't pay then then they will have an outstanding balance. All team payments go into a payments table which is getting bigger and bigger. What is the best practice to return a list of teams with their current balance?

**What I have at the moment:**

```
Select teams.*, (Select SUM(amount) from payments p where p.TeamID=teams.TeamID) as teambalance 
from (select TeamID, TeamName from Teams) teams
```

Comment: So "payments" are deleted (or amount updated to 0) when payments are made, thus teams with no balance have no records (or zero sum) in payments?

Comment: new payments are new rows in payments table. no rows mean balance is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have thought about this a lot and think that the classical advice of "don't store the same information twice" is mistaken here, or at least misinterpreted.

Think about how banks must do it. Obviously, when you want to know your current balance and you've been a customer for 20 years, they don't add up 20 years of account activity to find your current balance. In light of that, I see two ways to handle it:

1. Choose periods to "close" and always calculate from the last closed period. This keeps the summing relatively short. The monthly statement is probably a good such anchor. Do you have a similar natural time period or business life cycle to track with?
2. Work backwards, by anchoring your account history in the *present*. Instead of starting at 0 and adding, start at current balance and go back. This is just as valid, in my opinion, and has the added benefit that you don't have to do a thing when you want to trim old history. Store the current balance, and forget the supposed denormalization. The current balance is as true an empirical fact as the starting balance, and there is no harm in anchoring your accounts this way.

You can continue to add if you like, so long as performance is okay. But it may not be optimal.

Your current query is fine, but there is no need for the `teams` derived table. Unless you're using MySQL, the DBMS doesn't need this kind of "help"--though MySQL could actually be harmed by it.

Comment: In MySQL that subquery (derived table) would not help, it would be terrible, because it would require a temporary table when a table scan is the only thing needed.

Comment: Banks typically leverage things like materialized views.  You usually see a sum of balances that are 'outstanding' and those that are 'cleared'.  The 'cleared' transactions can all be handled from materialized views and you only have to looking at a small amount of data from detail tables for the non-cleared transactions.

Comment: Thanks @ErikE. I do like the idea of closing off old payments and implementing some kind of summary row for periods so i can just get the balance from the last summary and add any unclosed payments. 

When you say work backwards, does this mean I would have to have a balance column in the table for each row?

Comment: @Justin, if a simple derived table like that hinders MySQL performance it still pretty much proves my point. Is your point about cleared transactions any different from my idea #1? Also, what DBMS supports materialized views based on aggregates?

Comment: @Tallday Each open period would have to have a starting balance. Right now you use 0 so you don't have to store it, but you still use it. It would be a balance column *somewhere*, perhaps in a new `period` table. Or, you could treat it as a closing balance for prior periods and the current one has no closing balance, yet.

Comment: Oracle supports materialized views based on aggregates, and you can use my tool Flexviews (for MySQL) to create materialized views with aggregates.  Building a materialized view for an aggregate sum over a single table is trivial.  You can maintain the materialized view from the log without ever looking at the base table.

Comment: @Justin that's interesting about Oracle. For the MySQL solution, that's basically an out-of band trigger populating a data warehouse?

Comment: Conceptually it is like a trigger.  MySQL 5.1+ supports ROW level binary logs.  I wrote a processing utility that reads the ROW logs and makes table based change logs which contain a unique transaction id and global change number, along with the row changes.  The logs can then be used to update views incrementally.  The updates are asynchronous.  Flexviews lets you update a view to a particular point in time, so you could keep all of your views synchronized transactionally to the same point in time (like midnight).  Everything is stored procedures except the external log processing utility.

Comment: @Justin if you can update it, how is it a view? Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @ErikeE when I said "UPDATE" I mean "REFRESH", that is bringing the view up-to-date to a particular point in time.  BTW, there are also updatable views in RDBMSs.  Both Oracle and MySQL will allows views on single tables which include the primary key to be updated, for example.  Updates on the view will update the base table.  Updates to a Flexviews materialized view will never propagate to base tables.

Comment: That's what I mean--if there is no base table, how can it be a view? Sounds like a table, to me. I am amply familiar with materialized views in MS SQL Server--they have to reference a real table object unless they have all the data in their script (is that even possible?).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14925/discussion-between-justin-swanhart-and-erike)

Answer (score 1):

```
select teamId,teamName,sum(amount)
from teams t join payments p on t.teamId = p.teamId
group by t.teamId, t.teamName
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used two methods to accomplish this task - one being the method that you are currently using. The other is using cross apply.

I prefer your current method -

Answer (score 0):

This may be faster than using a subquery in the SELECT clause (or a join):

```
select teams.TeamID, teams.teamName, team_balances.teambalance
  from teams
  join ( select TeamID, sum(amount) teambalance
           from payments
         group by TeamID
  ) team_balances
  on team_balances.TeamID = teams.TeamID;
```

This will sequentially scan the payments table once, rather than doing N index scans (one per team).

**denormalizing**

Another option is to create add a "outstanding_balance" column to the teams table.

Create a trigger on the payments table.  In the trigger, increment or decrement the outstanding_balance column in teams based on the TeamID and the invoice/payment amount, respectively.

Depending on your RDBMS you could also use a materialized view.  This is similar to the trigger method, except the balance for each team would be stored in a different table.

Comment: Thanks @Justin. I like this trigger approach. Not something I have dont before so I will need to some investigation. My initial concerns are about the duplication of data. Is there any chance the column value could be different from the calculated value, are there delays in the trigger.

Comment: The trigger will execute in the same transaction as the modification to the row.  You won't be able to get out of sync.